# jQuery clicking some problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to click on li element and stay the same as hover element. here is my code  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/2/)

jQuery

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        border:2px solid #fff;
        height:22px;
        width:22px;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a unique class to the `li` on click

CSS

```
ul > li:hover, .hoverState{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    height:22px;
    width:22px;
    transition: all 0.08s linear;
}
```

JS

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
    //remove hoverState class from other element if any
    $('ul > li').removeClass('hoverState');

    //add hoverState class to the clicked element
    $(this).addClass('hoverState');
})
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/5/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a much better solution according to me, than adding inline styles.

JS:

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
})
```

CSS:

```
ul > li:hover, ul > li.clicked{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    height:22px;
    width:22px;
    transition: all 0.08s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the property value should be in the quotes like

```
border: "2px solid #fff"
```

because the arguments passed to the css method is an `object` , and properties ,which are also items in `object`, should be seperated by `,`

so it finally shoul be

```
$(this).css({
    border:"2px solid #fff",
    height:"22px",
    width:"22px",
    transition: "all 0.2s linear"
})
```

I usually pre-defined a class

```
.test{
    border:"2px solid #fff",
    height:"22px",
    width:"22px",
    transition: "all 0.2s linear"
}
```

and add it to the elemnt when event triggered

```
$(this).addClass("test");
```

in this way you can easily remove it just by

```
$(this).removeClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$` in `(this).css`

It should be like this:

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        border:'2px solid #fff',
        height:'22px',
        width:'22px',
        transition: 'all 0.2s linear'
    })
})
```

and also wrap the values within quotes and use `,` to separate the values.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

While you are missing the $ in the css, I believe you want the circle to stay filled if you click it

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/1/

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        border: "2px solid #fff",
        height: "22px",
        width: "22px",
        transition: "all 0.2s linear"
    })
})
```

If you want it to toggle back after clicking you would just detect the width or height, etc, and reverse the css attributes.

Hope this helps